# Django `bulk_create` with related objects

Tags: python, django, django-models, bulkinsert

I have a Django system that runs billing for thousands of customers on a regular basis. Here are my models:

```py
class Invoice(models.Model):
    balance = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=6,
        decimal_places=2,
    )

class Transaction(models.Model):
    amount = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=6,
        decimal_places=2,
    )
    invoice = models.ForeignKey(
        Invoice,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='invoices',
        null=False
    )
```

When billing is run, thousands of invoices with tens of transactions each are created using several nested `for` loops, which triggers an insert for each created record. I could run `bulk_create()` on the transactions for each individual invoice, but this still results in thousands of calls to `bulk_create()`.

How would one bulk-create thousands of related models so that the relationship is maintained and the database is used in the most efficient way possible?

Notes:

- I'm looking for a native Django solution that would work on all databases (with the possible exception of SQLite).
- My system runs billing in a celery task to decouple long-running code from active requests, but I am still concerned with how long it takes to complete a billing cycle.
- The solution should assume that other requests or running tasks are also reading from and writing to the tables in question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could `bulk_create` all the `Invoice` objects, refresh them from the db, so that they all have ids, create the `Transaction` objects for all the invoices and then also save them with `bulk_create`. All of this can be done inside a single `transaction.atomic` context.

Also, specifically for django 1.10 and postrgres, look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39314124/192390).

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with two bulk create queries, with following method.

```
new_invoices = []
new_transactions = []
for loop:
    invoice = Invoice(params)
    new_invoices.append(invoice)

    for loop: 
        transaction = Transaction(params)
        transaction.invoice = invoice
        new_transactions.append(transaction)

Invoice.objects.bulk_create(new_invoices)

for each in new_transactions:
    each.invoice_id = each.invoice.id

Transaction.objects.bulk_create(new_transactions)
```

Comment: I know official doc says `save / pre_save / post_save` method won't be called, is it the same case for this answer? I need `save` method called as I customize actions

Comment: Yes. save method wont be called.

Answer (score 0):

Another way for this purpose can be like the below code snippet:

```py
from django.utils import timezone
from django.db import transaction

new_invoices = []
new_transactions = []
for sth in sth_else:
    ...
    invoice = Invoice(params)
    new_invoices.append(invoice)

for sth in sth_else:
    ...
    new_transactions.append(transaction)

with transaction.atomic():
    other_invoice_ids = Invoice.objects.values_list('id', flat=True)
    now = timezone.now()
    Invoice.objects.bulk_create(new_invoices)

    new_invoices = Invoice.objects.exclude(id__in=other_invoice_ids).values_list('id', flat=True)
    for invoice_id in new_invoices:
                transaction = Transaction(params, invoice_id=invoice_id)
                new_transactions.append(transaction)

    Transaction.objects.bulk_create(new_transactions)
```

I write this answer based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17005170/11833435) on another question in the community.

Comment: I know official doc says `save / pre_save / post_save` method won't be called, is it the same case for this answer? I need `save` method called as I customize actions

Comment: `bulk_create` won't call `save()` method, if you need `save()` method you can create a `bulk_create()` for your manager or a new method do bulk create.