# Efficiently bulk updating many ManyToMany fields

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, many-to-many

A version of this question has been asked here several times but none of the answers provided solve my exact problem.

I'm trying to `bulk_create` a batch of objects of a model with a `ManyToMany` field.

In this case, the `ManyToMany` field refers to the same model, though I'd also be interested in the general case.

Let's say this is my model:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    friends = models.ManyToMany("self", related_name="friends_with", null=True)
```

After bulk_creating a large number of Person objects, I want to add the information who's friends with whom within this group.

Is there a more efficient way to go about this than looping through each new Person and calling `.set(friend_pks)` or `.add(*friend_pks)`?

I.e., an analogue of bulk_update.
I've achieved some speed-up by wrapping the loop into `with transaction.atomic()` (from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40791385/12689666) answer) but it's still quite slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, my post was premature -- it seems that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34090582/proper-way-to-bulk-create-for-manytomany-field-django) answers the question.

The key is to `bulk_create` the through models. In this example:

```
friends_relation_1 = Person.friends.through(from_person_id=1, to_person_id=2)
friends_relation_2 = Person.friends.through(from_person_id=2, to_person_id=8)

Person.friends.through.objects.bulk_create([friends_relation_1, friends_relation_2, ...])
```